# How to get the text of localized fields in VDM?

Tags: s4sdk

I'm trying to get business partner data from our S/4HANA Cloud (Public Cloud) by using VDM.

```
        final List<BusinessPartner> businessPartners =
                new DefaultBusinessPartnerService()
                        .getAllBusinessPartner()
                        .select(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER,
                                BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER_NAME)
                        .filter(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER_CATEGORY.eq("2"))
                        .orderBy(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER, Order.ASC)
                        .execute();
```

The English business partner name is displayed correctly.
But the Japanese business partner name is displayed as ?????.

```
{"BusinessPartner":"80000001","BusinessPartnerName":"Domestic US Customer 1"},
{"BusinessPartner":"80000002","BusinessPartnerName":"?????????????"},
{"BusinessPartner":"90000001","BusinessPartnerName":"Domestic US Supplier 1"},
{"BusinessPartner":"90000002","BusinessPartnerName":"????????"}
```

Could you give me advice how to get the text of localized fields?

Thanks.

(Additional notes)

I executed OData manually with Postman. In this case localized fields was displayed in Japanese.

```
https://myXXXXXX.s4hana.ondemand.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner?$select=BusinessPartner,BusinessPartnerName&$orderby=BusinessPartner&$filter=BusinessPartnerCategory%20eq%20'2'&$format=json&saml2=disabled
```

output

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "https://myXXXXXX.s4hana.ondemand.com:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner('80000001')",
                    "uri": "https://myXXXXXX.s4hana.ondemand.com:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner('80000001')",
                    "type": "API_BUSINESS_PARTNER.A_BusinessPartnerType"
                },
                "BusinessPartner": "80000001",
                "BusinessPartnerName": "Domestic US Customer 1"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "https://myXXXXXX.s4hana.ondemand.com:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner('80000002')",
                    "uri": "https://myXXXXXX.s4hana.ondemand.com:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner('80000002')",
                    "type": "API_BUSINESS_PARTNER.A_BusinessPartnerType"
                },
                "BusinessPartner": "80000002",
                "BusinessPartnerName": "東京得意先株式会社"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "https://myXXXXXX.s4hana.ondemand.com:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner('90000001')",
                    "uri": "https://myXXXXXX.s4hana.ondemand.com:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner('90000001')",
                    "type": "API_BUSINESS_PARTNER.A_BusinessPartnerType"
                },
                "BusinessPartner": "90000001",
                "BusinessPartnerName": "Domestic US Supplier 1"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "https://myXXXXXX.s4hana.ondemand.com:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner('90000002')",
                    "uri": "https://myXXXXXX.s4hana.ondemand.com:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner('90000002')",
                    "type": "API_BUSINESS_PARTNER.A_BusinessPartnerType"
                },
                "BusinessPartner": "90000002",
                "BusinessPartnerName": "東京仕入先株式会社"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you execute query the OData service manually (e.g., via Postman or in the browser) and provide the output of it as JSON?

Comment: @Emdee Thanks. I executed OData manually with Postman. In this case localized fields was displayed in Japanese. I added output to the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a `HttpServlet`, then make sure to set the character encoding of the `HttpServletResponse` object to `UTF-8` and the content type to `application/json` before writing the response.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked and I'm able to get the text fields in Japanese.